# When should I do lazy loading and how will this affect google search results?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, responsive-design

I'm thinking of diving into the '*progressive enhancement school of responsive web design' and I'm looking into lazy loading to increase page load time for mobile devices and for web pages with lot of content.

I've been reading a bit and while lazy loading sounds good, can it be over used? When should I not use lazy loading?

Also, if content is not loaded until I scroll down, how will this affect Google search engines as I will be using `jQuery` to fetch content? (let's assume that I have a site map)

**Update**
I just have a thought.
If I have a good site map and I index my pages in Google, lazy loading shouldn't affect google search result because the content is already indexed (in most cases).

Am I right?

Comment: Good question. It is better to know it exactly than roughly. The 'Most cases' can have no deal with your custom case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have to show a bunch of data and images on front end, you should use lazy loading, it will help you to display all text information on UI thread and images would be downloading on another thread, it will not affect your UI thread. Along with your Text info it will display all the images as per they would be downloaded on your system.

As per your question it does not affect for Google search, Images don't block anything, they are already lazy loaded. The on load event notifies you that all of the content has been downloaded, including images, but that is long after the document is ready.

Please check this link.

[lazy-loading img src negatively impact SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440998/would-lazy-loading-img-src-negatively-impact-seo)

Comment: Most likely standard implementation of lazy loading (based on initial replacing images by a placeholder) should break Google's Image Search (as `src=""` attribute doesn't refer to actual image).

Comment: I see three types of lazy loading (if I understand it correctly). 1) Content in some containers are loaded after main page is loaded 2) Content such as images is loaded but link to image is not set until user scrolls down 3) Content is only loaded when needed. For me, the last option is mot relevant in terms of reducing load time.